# CAShapeLayer is off center

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer, uicontrol

I have been trying to create a a custom "slider" or knob with `UIControl` for my app. I found [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5294-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-knob) tutorial and have been using it for some inspiration, but since it does not really accomplish what I want to do I am using it as more of a reference than a tutorial. Anyways, I wrote the code below and found that my CAShapeLayer was not in the center of the UIView that I set to be an instance of my custom class `CircularSelector`.

Here is my code:

```
    class CircularSelector: UIControl {
     
     
     private let renderer = CircularSelectorRenderer()
     
     override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       commonInit()
     }
     
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       commonInit()
     }
     
     private func commonInit() {
         
         renderer.updateBounds(bounds)
         //layer.borderWidth = 4
        // layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         layer.addSublayer(renderer.selectorLayer)
     }
     
 }


 class CircularSelectorRenderer {
     
     
     let selectorLayer = CAShapeLayer()
     
     init() {
         selectorLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
         selectorLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
         //Testing
         //selectorLayer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        // selectorLayer.borderWidth = 4
         
     }
     
     private func updateSelectorLayerPath() {
         let bounds = selectorLayer.bounds
         let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY)
         let radius = 125
         
         var ring = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: 0.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)
         
         selectorLayer.lineWidth = 10
         selectorLayer.path = ring.cgPath
         
     }
     
     func updateBounds(_ bounds: CGRect) {
         selectorLayer.bounds = bounds
         selectorLayer.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
         updateSelectorLayerPath()
         
     }
     
 }
```

This is what I get:

[image: Simulator]

and when I uncomment the code under the `//Testing` line in the `init()` of the `CircularSelectorRenderer` I get this:

[image: Simulator]

The grey UIView is of the class `CircularSelector`. I am confused as to why my `CAShapeLayer` is wider than the grey view itself and why it is not in the center of the grey view. Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: where are you setting the frame of the gray background?

Comment: Have you tried setting fixed width for the view in storyboard or calling `updateBounds(_ bounds: CGRect)` in `layoutSubviews` of custom view?

Comment: I am created the UIView in the storyboard and set leading and trailing constraints to a value of 20, I set the bottom to align with the safe area, and I set a height constraint of 150.

Comment: I just tried calling the updateBounds function adding in the layoutSubviews function (my custom class did not have it so I had to add it) and it seemed to work! Now I am just confused because in the tutorial I used for reference didn't need a layoutSubview function and the CAShapeLayer seemed to show up in the center just fine. I wonder what I am doing differently that caused this problem and if I will run into any unexpected problems down the road. Do you know why this worked, if it has any predictable side effects?

Comment: @Jithin Also if you have time I would be interested to know what I am doing differently from the tutorial.

Comment: I think in tutorial the view has fixed width in storyboard, so when you add the layer, it will be properly placed in view's bounds

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are updating the shape in the wrong place. Views can (and will) change sizes for different device sizes, superview sizes, device rotation, etc.

You want to update your shape layer when your view is told to layout its subviews:

```
class CircularSelector: UIControl {
    
    private let renderer = CircularSelectorRenderer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
        // no need to call this here
        //renderer.updateBounds(bounds)
        
        //layer.borderWidth = 4
        // layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        layer.addSublayer(renderer.selectorLayer)
    }

    // add this func
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // here is where you want to update the layer
        renderer.updateBounds(bounds)
    }

}
```